# Unity - get the dropdown in child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get the dropdown which is a child of OperationContainer.
My code gives the error "GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'dropdown' and no accessible extension method 'dropdown' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AddToPC : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject OperationContainer;
    
    void get_instruction(){
        
        Dropdown function = OperationContainer.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.dropdown;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) or [`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Dropdown component is attached to the children gameObject and try:

```
Dropdown function = OperationContainer.transform.GetComponentInChildren<Drompdown()>();
```

Comment: You might consider to pass in `true` just in case the according child is currently inactive the moment this is called